# How to write similar Retrofilt code for OKHTTP format?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

My OKHttp code is working fine but it's failing sometimes to get into ENQUEUE. It is not showing any information about it. I am trying to convert same code in Retrofit syntax. Can anybody help me out with the right syntax?

Below file1/2/3 are the image file paths.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                    .build();
            MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("text/plain");
            RequestBody body = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                    .addFormDataPart("photos1", String.valueOf(file1),
                            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"),
                                    new File(String.valueOf(file2)) ))
                    .addFormDataPart("photos2", String.valueOf(file2),
                            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"),
                                    new File(String.valueOf(file3)) ))
                    .addFormDataPart("photos3", String.valueOf(file3),
                            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"),
                                    new File(String.valueOf(file1)) ))
                    .addFormDataPart("product_name",txtprodname.getText().toString())
                    .addFormDataPart("description",txtdesc.getText().toString())
                    .addFormDataPart("product_cost",txtprice.getText().toString())
                    .addFormDataPart("tax_value",spntax.getSelectedItem().toString())
                    .addFormDataPart("within_city_cost",txtcostwithincity.getText().toString())
                    .addFormDataPart("outside_city_cost",txtcostoutsideincity.getText().toString())
                    .addFormDataPart("user_id",String.valueOf(user_id))
                    .addFormDataPart("category_name", spncategory.getSelectedItem().toString())
                    .addFormDataPart("tax_name",taxname)
                    .addFormDataPart("business_name", business_name)
                    .addFormDataPart("youtube_link", txtyoutube.getText().toString())
                    .addFormDataPart("length", txtL.getText().toString())
                    .addFormDataPart("width", txtW.getText().toString())
                    .addFormDataPart("height", txtH.getText().toString())
                    .addFormDataPart("volumetric_weight", txtwt.getText().toString())
                    .build();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://<myip>/api/productapi/")
                    .method("POST", body)
                    .build();

client.newCall(request).enqueue(new okhttp3.Callback() .... rest of the code.
```

I am not able to figure it out similar syntax for Retrofit. Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
PD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to send any file in API'S using Retrofit then you need to follow the below steps.

1. Retrofit initialization create class APIClient

```
public class APIClient {
    public static Retrofit retrofit;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS).readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS).writeTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://myapi.com")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .client(client)
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```

2. Create an Interface to list down API Keys consider interface name APiInterfacr.
   Most Important thing is to Assign DataType of ***RequerstBody*** to all your String/Int Data... and Assign ***MultiPartBody.Part*** to only file..
   Users is my Object Class you needs to create your Object Class and replace...

```
public interface APIInterface {
    @Multipart
    @POST("xyznode")
    Call<Users> updateUser(@Part("id") RequestBody id,
                           @Part("name") RequestBody name,
                           @Part("email") RequestBody email,
                           @Part("password") RequestBody password,
                           @Part("paypal_address") RequestBody paypal_address,
                           @Part("user_location") RequestBody user_location,
                           @Part("role_id") RequestBody role_id,
                           @Part MultipartBody.Part image_url);

}
```

3. now needs to call API.

```
  public void updateUser(RequestBody id, RequestBody name, RequestBody email, RequestBody password, RequestBody paypal_address, RequestBody user_location, MultipartBody.Part profile_photo_url, RequestBody role) {
        if (NetworkConnectivity.isOnline()) {
            Call<Users> call = apiInterface.updateUser(id, name, email, password, paypal_address, user_location, role, profile_photo_url);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<Users>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Users> call, Response<Users> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                     
           //Do your stuff here...
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Users> call, Throwable t) {
//
                }
            });
        } 
    }
```

4. Most important thing is to call this particular function, for this you needs to list down all the things required to parcel in your API...

```
                       RequestBody fileReqBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
                        profileImage = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("profile_photo_url", file.getName(), fileReqBody);
                        RequestBody id = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), preferencesHandler.getUid());
                        RequestBody name = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), txt_name);
                        RequestBody email = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), txt_email);
                        RequestBody password = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), txt_password);
                        RequestBody roleid = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), preferencesHandler.getRole());
                        RequestBody country = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), txt_country);
                        RequestBody paypal = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), txt_paypal);
```

5. Now call the function..

```
onUpdateUser(id, name, email, password, paypal, country, roleid, profileImage);
```

6. Dependency to add in your build file.

```
//Retrofit Dependency
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
```

Now you are ready to go... :-)

Comment: Ok i wil try to execute this pertaining to my code.

Comment: @user15226396 Ok and mark this as accepted if you get your answer...